# Ionic Android - Keyboard not showing on input focus

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have used CrossWalk chromeview on Android. Keyboard showing on input focus works fine on ios but doesn't work on android. I have tried almost every option I could find. Since I am an android programmer, I edited java files and tried many possible solutions from StackOverflow.

I am using javascript to focus on an input box.

I also tried the solution pointed out [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/How-to-show-and-hide-soft-keyboard-in-Android).

None of these works for me.

Has anyone solved this problem? Please help me it been a nightmare.

Comment: Is input focus triggered artificially or via user touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `ionic-plugins-keyboard` have not added open function. (Ionic seems to focus too little on Android)

However cordova plugin has already been updated.

Plugin:
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/944

Source code:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard

Documentation:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/

You can refer this: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-show-keyboard-on-input-focus-in-android/8088